# SELinux and cryptsetup: chown failed and can't access temporary keystore

Tags: encryption, selinux, luks

I am trying to set up SELinux and an encrypted additional partition that I mount at startup using a systemd service.

If I run SELinux in permissive mode, everything runs ok (partition is correctly mounted, data can be accessed and service runs properly).

If I run SELinux in enforcing mode (enforcing=1), I am not able to mount such partition with the error:

```
/dev/mapper/temporary-cryptsetup-1808: chown failed: Permission denied
sh[1777]: Failed to open temporary keystore device.
sh[1777]: Command failed with code 5: Input/output error
```

Any ideas to fix that?

Audit2allow does not return any additional rules to be added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved assigning to cryptsetup the `lvm_exec_t` context.

In the `lvm.fc` file cryptsetup was defined as `/bin/cryptsetup` but I had to change it to `/usr/sbin/cryptsetup` where it actually was.